# python convert CSV with comas inside values into Dictionary

Tags: python, list, csv

I need to process some CSV data I get from an external provider I can't control.

The data has a fixed amount of columns, but variable amounts of rows.

To summarize, it can look like this:

```
Version,Relative Path,Author,Date,Comment,Link
1,somePath,someperson,01/20/2020,"Some phrase with punctuation including comas, but in which case it seems to be automatically formatted with quotes...",some.url
3,somePath,someperson,01/20/2020,Simple comment with no punctuation,another.url
50,somePath,someperson,01/20/2020,Another comment,some.url
```

AFAIK the best way for me to do it is using this:

```py
import csv

with open("sample.csv", "r") as csvFile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvFile)
    data = {}
    for row_dict in reader:
        for key, value in row_dict.items():
            data[key] = data.get(key, []) + [value]

print(data)
```

And the result looks great! Except for the "Comment" column: as the comments have punctuations, and the CSV delimiter is `,`, this leads to the script splitting these commands into different items and messing up the dictionary.

I wish I could ask the provider to make a specific CSV output for me, but that's unlikely to happen.

HOWEVER: it looks like any comment item that contains such commas inside are provided between quotation marks `"`. So I was wondering if I could somehow make the delimiter ignore whatever's between quotes?

Or if you have anything better to obtain the same result, I'm fine with it. Though I can only use vanilla python 3.10.2, no modules like numpy (even though I'd love it). And if the solution is to edit the CSV's content, then it should preserve the comas inside the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solve a similar situation...

```
quote_character='"'    
file_reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=delimiter, quotechar=quote_character,
                                             restkey='unrecognized_cols')
```

Note the *quotechar* parameter.

Comment: Via `for i in data['Comment']:print(i);break;print(data['unrecognized_cols'])`, I see it ignores the comment part between the first quote and following coma, and dumps the rest of the row to a different key :(

Comment: So, it still thinks the field breaks at the comma after comas? Can you show what that print statement produces? Maybe better, print(str(data)) for that first row?

Comment: I tried again this morning and it worked :o I guess I really should not program at night.... Thanks for the help x)

Comment: From reading the documentation about [CSV](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#dialects-and-formatting-parameters), I understand that it's supposed to already use `"` and `,` as default `quotechar` and `delimiter`, but for some reason in my script it doesn't work if I specify them manually. Good to know, defaults are not to be trusted 100%

Comment: @L0Lock Thanks! TBH, I forgot they were defaults. I use them explicitly because sometimes my files might have other quote characters and delimiters, like ' and |. Glad it worked!